# Filter multiple bindings

Tags: angularjs

I have multiple bindings in my angular template

```
 <span class="info__text">
  {{ ::row.brand_name }} {{ ::row.model }}
 </span>
```

And the following filter which  should return value or N/A when the value is not  available.

```
angular.module('common').filter('naOrVal', () => {
  return (val)=> {
    return val === null || val === '' ? 'N/A' : val;
  }
});
```

I would like to apply this filter to both bindings at the  same time so that when the whole expression evaluates to null or empty string I will see N/A. If only one of them is available - I'll get its value and no  N/A.

I can surely workaround the case but I'd like to use filter piping and one one-time data binding too

{{value | filter}}

Comment: One question. The usage of filter worked with one binding value? {{ :: row.brand_name | naOrVal }}

Comment: the filter does work

Answer (score 0):

you can use a test for the second case.
you don't need the filter at second case because the condition doesn't will catch the else on the filter:

```
{{ ::row.brand_name | naOrVal }} 
{{ (::row.model === null || ::row.model === '') ? '' : ::row.model }}
```

Comment: another option is to create (and implement) an optional default text for the filter: {{ ::row.model | naOrVal | '' }}, specifically for the second or others cases.